# Find records by specific two names mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I want to fetch the records by two specific names in single column but this query is not working for me,

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM orders_custom oc 
    INNER JOIN group_options go 
    ON oc.group_option_id = go.group_option_id 
    WHERE orderedProduct_id = '40476' 
        AND go.is_default = 1 
        AND oc.group_name = 'size' 
        AND oc.group_name = 'base'
```

what is the proper way to write it?

Comment: What is orderedProduct_id and which table has this field?

Comment: orders_custom table has this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM orders_custom oc 
INNER JOIN group_options go ON oc.group_option_id = go.group_option_id 
WHERE orderedProduct_id = '40476' 
    AND go.is_default = 1 
    AND oc.group_name in ('size','base')
```

Or you can specify the name conditions in a `OR` clause

```
AND (oc.group_name = 'size' OR oc.group_name = 'base' OR ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

last `oc.group_name` you should use `OR` or `IN`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OR`, see example below:

```
SELECT * FROM orders_custom oc 
INNER JOIN group_options go 
    ON oc.group_option_id = go.group_option_id 
WHERE orderedProduct_id = '40476' AND go.is_default = 1 AND (oc.group_name = 'size' OR oc.group_name = 'base')
```